# asp page will not render on 2012 web server

Tags: asp-classic, iis-8.5

I am moving some old applications over to a new server and I am receiving a 500 error, with the IIS log having the below:

2015-03-20 20:24:28 192.168.28.131 GET /test.asp |33|ASP_0177_:_800401f3|Server.CreateObject_Failed 80 - *IP ADDRESS* Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 500 0 0 0

**Here is my environment:**

- The test server is Windows 2012 R2
- IIS - version 8.5
- I already have an asp.net web site running.  (this rules out turn windows features on or off).
- The new web site is pointing to the Default App Pool (for now).

**I tested to see if it was my code, but not the case:**

- I created a file called test.Html which just says "Hello".  If I browse to that url the page comes up fine.
- If I rename the test.html file to test.asp, the error occurs.

I then tried the below basic .asp script, same error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<%
response.write("Hello World!")
%>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the classic asp is also enabled rather than .net?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour - `Server.Createobject_Failed` suggests that Classic ASP is enabled

Comment: Somewhere in test.asp you should have the instruction `Server.CreateObject("some.objectname")`.  What sort of object is it trying to create?  There are a few possibilities.  It could be a third party component which was present on your old server but not on your new one.  It could be a 32 bit component and you haven't enabled 32 bit applications in your app pool.

Comment: Ali, under Turn windows features on or off / Add Roles and Features Wizard / Server Roles, then select from the window: Web Server (IIS) / Web Server / Application Development the checkbox for ASP is checked and says installed next to it.

Comment: John,  I have never worked with ASP before except changed some text values, images .. so this old stuff is somewhat new.  I added the CODE I am trying to execute original question and as you can see the only .ASP executed is the response.write.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure You've enabled classic ASP on IIS?
The server role has to be installed, because on default it isn't on IIS 8.5.
In the server manager go to IIS roles and add ASP in the Development tab.
Install it and now it should work!

Comment: As mentionted earlier.. When I go to Turn windows features on or off / Add Roles and Features Wizard / Server Roles, then select from the window: Web Server (IIS) / Web Server / Application Development the checkbox for ASP is checked and says installed next to it